# How to use mode 0 in 8051?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I tried to use timer0 in mode 0 of AT89S52 for blinking a led for 1 second using this code:

```c
#include<REG52.h>

//XTAL frequency is 16.000 MHz 

sbit led = P1^0;

void delay(int a)
{
    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < a; z++)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TMOD = 0x00;
            TL0 = 0x1f;
            TH0 = 0xa4;
            TR0 = 1;
            while (TF0 == 1)
            {
                TR0 = 0;
                TF0 = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    led = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        led = 1;
        delay(1000);
        led = 0;
        delay(1000);
    }
}
```

But the the delay that generated is not 1 second.

Is there a way to generate a 1 second delay from 13 bit timer mode?

Comment: What is the actual delay generated ? Also, `while(TF0 == 1){TR0 = 0;` **`TF0`** `= 0;}`. The loop is immediately terminated ?

Comment: about 100 ms or 200ms

Comment: The `while` loop in my comment will execute only **once** since `TF0` is set to `0` in the first pass through the loop itself. Was that your intention ? Can you add comments to the code explaining each line especially the while loop ?

Comment: do you have a code for using mode 0 for blinking ?

Comment: How many times does the while loop execute ? Can you add comments to the code explaining the logic ?

Answer (score 0):

The loop waiting for the timer is run not at all, if `TF0` is not set, or only once, because it resets the flag `TF0` right in the first iteration:

```c
            while (TF0 == 1)
            {
                TR0 = 0;
                TF0 = 0;
            }
```

Instead, reset the flag and then wait for it to be set by the timer:

```c
            TF0 = 0;
            while (TF0 == 0)
            {
                /* nothing to be done here */
            }
```